# How to display image from mysql to my program visual c++?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm write this code. It show error message (parameter is not valid)
How can solve it?

```
 String^ con=L"datasource=localhost; port=3306;username=root; password=411126;";
             MySqlConnection ^ conn=gcnew MySqlConnection(con);
             MySqlCommand^ cmd=gcnew MySqlCommand("select img from info.images where id='"+textBox1->Text+"'",conn);
             MySqlDataReader^re;
             try{
                 conn->Open();
                 re=cmd->ExecuteReader();
                 [![enter image description here][1]][1]re->Read();
                 BinaryFormatter^fe=gcnew BinaryFormatter();
                 BinaryFormatter();
                 MemoryStream^ms=gcnew MemoryStream();
                 fe->Serialize(ms,re["img"]);
                 array<Byte>^arr =ms->ToArray();
                 MemoryStream^ms2=gcnew MemoryStream(arr);
                 pictureBox1->Image=Image::FromStream(ms2);
             }
             catch(Exception^ex){
                 MessageBox::Show(ex->Message,"ERROR");
             }
```

Comment: i would step through the code and figure out which line is throwing the error.

Comment: It show messageBox "parameter is not valid"

Comment: I get that -- but what line throws that error? If you step through, you'll be able to see at what point it jumps down to the catch block

Comment: On this line         pictureBox1->Image=Image::FormStream(ms2);

Comment: i would assume `ms2` is either null or empty. There is a chance `ms` doesn't contain what you'd hope it does. I would view the contents of the `ms` memory stream.